# $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$-module structure on a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, p-adic-number-theory, graded-rings

I am trying to make sense of Definition 1.9 in the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf). See my [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716314/graded-ring-defined-via-a-sequence-of-abelian-groups) from earlier today.

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $Z_{(p)}$ be the localisation of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $p\mathbb{Z}$ i.e. $$Z_{(p)}=\lbrace\frac{a}{b}:a,b\in\mathbb{Z},b\notin p\mathbb{Z}\rbrace.$$ For each non-negative integer $k$, choose a generator $\alpha_k$ for the cyclic group of order $p^{v_p(k)+1}$. This cyclic group can then be written as $$\lbrace 1,\alpha_k,\alpha_k^2,\ldots,\alpha_k^{p^{v_p(k)}}\rbrace.$$ Looking at the first line defining the multiplications, it appears that there must be a $Z_{(p)}$-module structure on the above-defined cyclic group, but I can't see how this can be the case.

How can, say, $\frac{1}{2}\alpha_k$ be defined? It seems that we must be able to find fractional multiples of $\alpha_k$ for this definition to make any sense. Have I missed something?

Comment: Define $\frac{a}{b}\cdot\alpha_k:=\alpha_k^{a/b}$, which is well-defined, since $b$ is invertible modulo $p^{v(k)+1}$.